# How to pause timers on breaks?

Tags: visual-c++, timer, break

I'm using `SetTimer` in my app. I want the timers I use to pause when the the app reaches a breakpoint and resume at continue, but I haven't found relevant info. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time keeps on slippin slippin slippin into the fuuuuture. You can't freeze the operating system clock.

This happens without a debugger breakpoint as well.  It is a good test for what happens to your program when it runs on a heavily loaded machine or is subjected to lots of page faults.  If it misbehaves now with the debugger then it will also misbehave in impossible to diagnose ways on the user's machine.